# Datepicker não aplica mudanças realizadas

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap-3

Estou utilizando o datepicker do bootstrap, porém quando faço algumas modificações elas não se aplicam

```
var defaults = $.fn.datepicker.defaults = {
        autoclose: false,
        beforeShowDay: $.noop,
        calendarWeeks: false,
        clearBtn: true,
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [],
        endDate: Infinity,
        forceParse: true,
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        keyboardNavigation: true,
        language: 'pt',*
        minViewMode: 0,
        multidate: false,
        multidateSeparator: '-',
        orientation: "auto",
        rtl: false,
        startDate: -Infinity,
        startView: 0,
        todayBtn: false,
        todayHighlight: false,
        weekStart: 0
    };
```

*coloquei a linguagem pt e alterei tbm aqui:

```
var dates = $.fn.datepicker.dates = {
        en: {
            days: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
            daysShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
            daysMin: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"],
            months: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
            monthsShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
            today: "Today",
            clear: "Clear"
        },

       pt: {
            days: ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado", "Domingo"],
            daysShort: ["Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "Sab", "Dom"],
            daysMin: ["Do", "Sg", "Te", "Qa", "Qi", "Sx", "Sa", "Do"],
            months: ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"],
            monthsShort: ["Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"],
            today: "Hoje",
            clear: "Limpar"
        }

    };
```

Usando da seguinte maneira:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    Início do período:
    <input type="text" id="calendarioIni" name="dataInicio">
    Fim do período:
    <input type="text" id="calendarioFim" name="dataFim"> 
    <input style="display: none;" type="submit" value="Consultar" />                                    
    <br><br><br>

    <?php if(isset($_POST['dataInicio']) && isset($_POST['dataFim']))
    {
        $dataIni = $_POST['dataInicio'];
        $dataFim = $_POST['dataFim'];
        echo $dataIni."<br>";//Teste para verificar o valor nas variáveis que recebem a data via POST
        echo $dataFim."<br>";
    } 
    ?>                                    
</form>
```

Quando abro o calendario ele está em inglês, como faço para aplicar essa modificação?

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $('#calendarioIni').datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            startDate: '01/01/1998', // 1 de Janeiro de 1998
            endDate: '31/12/1998', // 31 de Janeiro de 1998,
            language: "pt-BR",
            onSelect: checaVazio
        });
});
```

Comment: mas continua em inglês

Comment: Não precisaria fazer isso. Basta incluir esse script oficial no seu código: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pt-BR.min.js"></script>` e colocar a opção `language: "pt-BR"` no seu elemento.

Comment: quando coloco language: "pt-BR" o calendário nem abre mais

Comment: Você está fazendo algo errado. Olha a resposta do Marcos abaixo.

Comment: realmente, tinha esquecido de uma vírgula, mas mesmo assim, ainda continua em inglês e a do Marcus não funcionou também

Comment: Agora que fui reparar, no Chrome fica em inglês, mas no Mozila e no IE fica em português...

Comment: No Chrome aqui fica em PT-BR normalmente. Olha minha resposta abaixo. Está funcionando.

Comment: Faltou uma vírgula depois de `language: "pt-BR"`... é preciso colocar sempre uma virgula no final de cada linha dentro do objeto, para separar os valores, exceto na última linha. Sem essa única vírgula, dá erro no script todo.

Comment: Sim DvD, corrigi isto já, só tinha esquecido de editar aqui, até comentei aqui, se vc observar uns comentários acima verá.
Paulo, eu já tinha visto a sua implementação, mas no meu projeto tem alguma coisa muito errada que tá dando uns erros bem estranhos

Comment: Se algum plugin não estiver conflitando com o *jQuery*, não sei o que pode ser.

Comment: Tenho quase certeza que é conflito mesmo, mas não sei como corrigir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

utilize a tradução do datapiker

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/boot‌​strap-datepicker/js/‌​locales/bootstrap-da‌​tepicker.pt-BR.min.j‌​s"></script>

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
   language: 'pt-BR'
});
```

Ou tente de  forma direta

**Vc pode definir os padrões globais antes de definir os inputs:**

```
$(function () {
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    showOn: "focus",
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    dayNames: ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarte", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"],
    dayNamesMin: ["Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "Sab"],
    monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro']
});
```

**Ou pode definir os atributos de cada input individualmente:**

```
$(function () {
 $("#data").datepicker({
    showOn: "focus",
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    dayNames: ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarte", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"],
    dayNamesMin: ["Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "Sab"],
    monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro']
 });
});
```

OBS: Cuidado. Não é uma boa prática de programação alterar a biblioteca manualmente. Só recorra a isso se não houver outro jeito de resolver seu "problema".

Fonte: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: testei as duas formas, quando uso os padrões globais o calendario não aparece e no input individual continua em inglês

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo testado e funcionando:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#data').datepicker({
    language: 'pt-BR'
  });
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pt-BR.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="data">
```

Answer (score -1):

Você tem que colocar o nome que você colocou no dates

```
var dates = $.fn.datepicker.dates = {
       pt: {
            days: ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado", "Domingo"],
            daysShort: ["Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "Sab", "Dom"],
            daysMin: ["Do", "Sg", "Te", "Qa", "Qi", "Sx", "Sa", "Do"],
            months: ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"],
            monthsShort: ["Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"],
            today: "Hoje",
            clear: "Limpar"
        }

};

$(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $('#calendarioIni').datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            startDate: '01/01/1998', // 1 de Janeiro de 1998
            endDate: '31/12/1998', // 31 de Janeiro de 1998,
            language: "pt",
            onSelect: checaVazio
        });
});
```